# <?php get_search_form(); ?> cannot show on my web

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a navigation bar, and I want to add a search bar on it.

```
<nav>
        <div class="wrapper">
            
            <input type="radio" name="slide" id="cancel-btn">
            <input type="radio" name="slide" id="menu-btn">
            
            <?php
                wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'theme_location' => 'primary',
                    "menu_class" => "nav-links",
                    "items_wrap"  => '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                    'container' => false,
                    "walker" => new Custom_Menu_Walker(),
                ));
            ?>

            <div class="icon-list">
            
                <!-- for fb coneection -->
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/PacFeng" target="_blank" id="fb"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                <!-- for ig coneection -->
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/pacific_feng_blog/" target="_blank" id="ig"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <!-- for mail coneection -->
                <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?fs=1&to=pacfeng@gmail.com&tf=cm&su=Pacific峰的部落格 讀者來信了喔!!" target="_blank" id="mail"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i></a>
                <!-- for search -->
                <!-- <a href=# target="_blank" id="search"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></a> -->
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </div>

            
            
            <label for="menu-btn" class=" btn menu-btn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label> <!-- for the RWD bar icon -->
        </div>
    </nav>
```

But the search bar on the web is 33.33x0 (show as picture below)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTGrV.png)

How can I solve it?

Best regards

I want to make it appear in my navigation bar (If I move out of the  tag, it will show, and I have no idea why)

Comment: When you view the page’s source, do you see the expected HTML? Maybe CSS is just hiding it? Do you have a file called `searchform.php`?

Comment: I have edited the description picture above, and it exactly show the expected HTML showing in the picure.

I have checked the CSS, and it is not the problem of CSS. Once I move the '<?php get_search_form ?>' out of the <nav> bar, its height become normal. I have no idea why it has this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason:

I set the CSS :

```
.wrapper input {
  display: none;
}
```

which will effect the wordpress comment form for showing.